# OpenGL and DirectX

Tags: java, opengl, directx

Can somebody explain to me the dumb version of what OpenGL and directX is? Were they both created by pure computer language like java, c++, C#, Objective C or are they a language all to themselves. In other words LGjWL uses openGL right? So was it created straight from the pure Java API like when you create your own package in java?

Comment: here you go.. "OpenGL vs DirectX: The War Is Far From Over" 
http://rastergrid.com/blog/2011/10/opengl-vs-directx-the-war-is-far-from-over/

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to connect both to a primitive language. I was looking up OpenGL and the code they use looks alot like java, but was it derived from java itself. I do not want a comparison of the two I would like both explained in a dumbed down version.

Comment: quick&short note - technically OpenGL and DirectX are not languages but rather specification of instructions and/or graphic processing operations, which are implemented in electronic chips, and use of which is implemented in libraries available to be used in programming languages you specified. Thinking about OpenGL as programming language, you probably mean GLSL ( GL Shaders Language ), or its equivalent for DirectX.

Comment: ah, okay, but were they expansions of the languages. For Example: theoretically could I make my own version of OpenGL simply by making an API of my own with my own packages and methods etc.

Comment: probably not, unless you want to design internals of GPU as well. You can theoretically create your own IMPLEMENTATION of OpenGL ( e.g. for use with specific language ), however it will still call same instructions on graphic card as they do in libraries already implemented. So, possibilities of your implementation would be limited by operations possible to be performed by graphic chip.

Comment: so is that what LGJWL is an implementation, it uses OpenGL so I assume it is an implementation. So OpenGL can be downloaded for a specified language and added to the API and be used to create hybrid versions of the specific language to handle graphics better than the pure language itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL and DirectX are APIs: Application Programming Interfaces.

APIs are set of callables (functions) and tokens (numeric constants) forming an interface that provides certain functionalities to programs. OpenGL is an API that allows programs to draw nice pictures. DirectX is an umbrella for a whole set of sub APIs, for sound, graphics, user input, etc.

APIs *are not* languages!

APIs *are not* written in some programming language.

APIs *are* merely documents in which a certain system behavior is described and the way it can be invoked. Those documents are usually written in technical English.

---

What you actually have on your computer are not the pure APIs, but some actual *implementation*. The implementation of an API can be written in any language, as long as it can be translated to, or provide directly the interfaces as specified in the API documentation. Of course using a language, which directly supports the calling convention as specified by the API greatly simplifies things.